# Get Image location from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photosframework

I have tried multiple ways to get the location of an image which took through the `UIImagePickerController Camera`.

What I want to achieve is that, I want to select an image using `UIImagePickerController` `Camera` and I have to save it into `Photo Library` so that only I can take back the `PHAsset` from it and also the location associated with it.

```
   //MARK: Saving an Image to PhotoLibrary and taking back the PHAsset

    class func savingThis(image : UIImage, completion : (asset : PHAsset?) -> ())
    {
        var localIdentifier : String?
        let imageManager = PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary()

        imageManager.performChanges({ () -> Void in

            let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)

            if let properAsset = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset {
                localIdentifier = properAsset.localIdentifier
            }
            else {
                completion(asset: nil)
            }

            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in

                if let properLocalIdentifier = localIdentifier {

                    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers([properLocalIdentifier], options: nil)
                    if result.count > 0  {
                        completion(asset: result[0] as? PHAsset)
                    }
                    else {
                        completion(asset: nil)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    completion(asset: nil)
                }
        })
    }
```

I have tried this code, to save and get back the PHAsset. But the problem is that this `PHAsset` does not have any location associated with it, wondering why? And what I missed?

I believe that I don't have to manually set `GPS` data into image's metadata right? I think that `Photos Framework` or `Asset Library` takes care of it. So as you know that `Asset Library` is deprecated our only option is to use `Photos Framework`. I read online that, Saving image to `Photo Library` takes care of it. Isn't it correct?

Is there any alternative? Should I use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` method to save image to `Camera Roll`, And I can take back the very recent photo using `Photos Framework`. But I don't think that `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` will take care of the location thing.

Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: are you trying to get the path of the image?

Comment: I am using UIImagePickerController to take a new photo by setting Camera as the source type in the UIImagePickerController. After selecting the image, I am saving the image to Photo Library, and take it back as PHAsset. The PHAsset does not have any location associated with it, I want location with the PHAsset.

Answer (score 2):

First of all thanking all who were all kind to take a look into the question.

I found my answer.

```
  //MARK: Saving an Image to PhotoLibrary and taking back the PHAsset

    class func savingThis(image : UIImage, completion : (asset : PHAsset?) -> ())
    {
        var localIdentifier : String?
        let imageManager = PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary()

        imageManager.performChanges({ () -> Void in

            let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)

            request.location = // Assigned current location here :)

            if let properAsset = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset {
                localIdentifier = properAsset.localIdentifier
            }
            else {
                completion(asset: nil)
            }

            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in

                if let properLocalIdentifier = localIdentifier {

                    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers([properLocalIdentifier], options: nil)

                    if result.count > 0   {
                        completion(asset: let asset = result[0] as? PHAsset)
                    }
                    else {
                        completion(asset: nil)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    completion(asset: nil)
                }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get a callback from `UIImagePickerController`:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo 
                               info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {}
```

you can try to get the image location from the info dictionary.
For that, you need to request the related `PHAsset` object:

```
if let assetImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {
    print("Image location info =  \( assetImage.location))")
}
```

Important - before using this approach you need to request the user permission:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization()
```

If you do not do it the info dictionary for `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset` will return `nil`.